# spark scala get the last character from two columns and concatenate them

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I have two columns col1 and col2 and they have string values  how can I create a third column by adding the last character from both

Comment: Which one would you prefer? doing sql? or udf? or spark apis?

Comment: @AminMal
  spark api

Answer (score 1):

As you replied to the comment, you want to use spark api, then follow this:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = ??? // which contains col1 and col2
df.withColumn("col3", concat(
  substring(col("col1"), -1, 1),
  substring(col("col2"), -1, 1)
))
```

I tried with this:

```
df: 
+---------+------+
|     col1|  col2|
+---------+------+
|   random|string|
|generated|    rn|
+---------+------+

result:
+---------+------+----+
|     col1|  col2|col3|
+---------+------+----+
|   random|string|  mg|
|generated|    rn|  dn|
+---------+------+----+
```

**Other Approaches**

using udf:

```scala
val concatLastChars: (String, String) => String = 
  (s1, s2) =>
    s1.last + s2.last

spark.udf.register("custom_concat_name", concatLastChars)
// then when selecting
df.withColumn("col3", expr("custom_concat_name(col1, col2)"))
```

You can also use spark sql with the same function `SUBSTRING` with the same args to get what you want.